# Openshift 3: How to create a cron job?

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I have been trying to create a cron job on my Openshift 3 Starter app.  I have read the docs [HERE](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html) but I guess I'm not understanding them correctly.

I would like run a simple python tcron.py  script that prints out a timestamp  every minute.  I have tried the following to set up the cron job.

```
 oc run tcron --schedule="* * * * *" --image=python --restart=OnFailure -- python vscan/tcron.py
```

The above command gives me the error:

```
 Error from server (Forbidden): User "<MY EMAIL ACCOUNT>" cannot create cronjobs.batch in the namespace "vscan": User "<MY EMAIL ACCOUNT>" cannot create cronjobs.batch in project "vscan" (post cronjobs.batch)
```

What is the correct way of creating a cron job on openshift 3 starter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jobs are only available in the OpenShift Online Pro environments. You can see what you get in Starter compared to Pro at:

- https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I missed that.  I was used to Openshift 2 having cron jobs in their starter plan.

Comment: I used to use cron jobs in Openshift 2 as well. Have you found some other free online service allowing one to run scripts periodically?